# Google analytics.js error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE

Tags: google-analytics

I'm needing to do some testing with analytics, for what i deleted the IP filter that ignores my visits to my site. But for some reason it doesn't work.
This is what I get in the console

```
   GET https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I checked the other questions with the same/similar problem and i did the following:

- Disabled AdBlock
- Checked host file
- Puted the traking code inside the `<head>` tag

This is my site: http://galagourmet.com.ar , I'm using Wordpress.

Thanks!

UPDATE: I know it's not a problem from my computer, because it also happens with my cellphone when i used my house's wi-fi. So it must be a network problem

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is a browser error, so this would seem to a local problem. FWIW, when I check your site GA is executed without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i solved it. As i suspected it was a network problem. I dont really know what was the problem, but **resetting the router solved it**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend checking your `/etc/hosts` file. I was using one that I found online, that was blocking analytics.google.com as a whole. Once I removed that entry, it worked fine.